# how to make a button to have the functionality of radio button in IOS

Tags: ios

i have 5 buttons if each of the button is pressed the background should be changed. if i select the next button the previously pressed button background should be changed to normal background and the selected button background should be changed (like a radio button). How can i achieve this can any one please help me.

```
- (IBAction)butclaim2:(id)sender 
{ 
if ([sender isSelected]) 
 { 
  [butClaim2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i_radiobutton_full.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [sender setSelected: NO]; 
  } 
  else 
   { 
    [sender setSelected: YES]; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: can you show your tried code...

Comment: - (IBAction)butclaim2:(id)sender {
    
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
         [butClaim2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"i_radiobutton_full.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setSelected: NO];
    } else {
        [sender setSelected: YES];
    }
   
}
this is the sample code.

Comment: you can implemnt in multiple ways , wait I submit my answer, one more question yours buttons are  subview of scrollview or subview or UIView

Comment: the buttons are designed in xib.and loaded in view controller.

Answer (score 0):

assume that your buttons are subview of `UIView`, for example

**Step -1**

create a one Global `NSMutableArray` for store the `Button`, like

```
buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5]; // reason u have 5 buttons
```

**Step-2**

```
 create button progrmatically else if your button has already added in connection attribute ,just add the button to array

    //Initially set all Image are off mode 
    [RadioBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //create the common method for all Buttons
    [RadioBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:RadioBtn1];


    [RadioBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [RadioBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:RadioBtn2];


    [RadioBtn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [RadioBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:RadioBtn3];


    [RadioBtn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [RadioBtn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:RadioBtn4];


    [RadioBtn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [RadioBtn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.buttonsArray addObject:RadioBtn5];
```

**Step-3**

```
- (IBAction)RadioButton:(UIButton*)sender{

   //selection reset all buttons to normal state
   [self resetAllButtonsonNormalMode];

   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

**Step-4**

```
-(void) resetAllButtonsonNormalMode{
       for(int i=0;i<[self.buttonsArray count];i++){
          UIButton* button=[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
          [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
  }
```

Comment: if you want the sample tutorial see this link http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/

Comment: @Arun -- sure my bro, if you need assistance ask here

Comment: Anbu thanks for your help.I used picker view which makes my work easier. Thanks a lot Anbu.

Comment: @Arun -- I Used this answer in multiple ways , it is work well, can you upvote for this answer , it is useful for some one

Comment: Anbu can you send me the full demo code to my mail, I will check.